# Annonymous access to a page without enabling anonymous authentication on site

Tags: sharepoint-server, anonymous-authentication

I have developed a visual webpart and want to add it on a page. The page containing the Webpart should be accessed anonymously.

I cannot enable anonymous authentication at the web application level. Is there any way to access a single page anonymously in SharePoint without enabling anonymous authentication on site.

Some of the users who don't have AD accounts (Guests users) should be able to access the page without login

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try breaking inheritance of that page and give permissions to `Everyone` (All users).

Comment: I don't have anonymous authentication enabled for the web application and I can't enable this. Can you suggest any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another site (where You give "Everyone") Visitor access and place the page with the web part there.

BUT if the web part is supposed to show (roll up) information that is access controlled it will not help where You place it since the items might not are visible for those with only Visitor access.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My requirement is some of the users who don't have AD accounts (Guests users) should be able to access the page without login.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before, my solution is to configure the web application level with anonymous access, and manage the permissions very carefully.
But I think you could create a new web application which has anonymous access and let your web part visite the necessary data of your current site. So that you can only care about the permission of new web application. It's more secure.